# Rails Query transformation for Rails 4.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm upgrading from Rails 3.2.12 to 4.2.0

Most things are working now, but one query is a problem. Don't know how to transform it for 4.2.0

```
user_lesson = self.user_lessons.find :first,
              :include => [:lesson],
              :conditions => ["worked = ? AND passed = ?", true, false],
              :order => "lessons.sort"
```

I have a second one with problems

```
memberships = Membership.find :all,
     :include => [:course],
     :conditions => ["next_mindmail < ? AND course_objects.active = ?", DateTime.now.utc, true]
```

I tried this:

```
memberships = Membership.joins(:course).where("next_mindmail < ? AND active = ?", DateTime.now.utc, true).all
```

But it seems not to be the same...

Comment: hm tried this bevore and got errors, I try it again and give feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.users.includes(:lesson).where("worked = ? AND passed = ?, true, fale).order('lessons.sort').first`

All rails query interfaces are [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: thanks, I've added a second one above There I got problems as well

Comment: @Felix you don't need .all here Also read about joins/includes and when use it

Answer (score 1):

That order by "lesson.sort" looks like it could be included within the association if it's a common operation that is applied whenever you join user_lessons and lessons. Even if it's more rare, you're only going to get effective eager loading for multiple user_lessons by including it in an association.

The other conditions might be a scope, if they're common clauses.

This would leave you with something like:

```
user_lesson = self.user_lessons.
                join(:lesson_by_sort).
                where(worked: true, passed: false).
                first
```

Or maybe:

```
user_lesson = self.user_lessons.
                failed.
                join(:lesson_by_sort).
                first
```

... where user_lessons has:

```
def self.failed
  where(worked: true, passed: false)
end
```